# Using Kube-state-metrics in prometheus to get the total number of containers running on a node

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql, kube-state-metrics

kube-state-metrics allows me to find the number of pods running on each node by running

```
sum by (node) (kube_pod_info)
```

I can get the number of containers in every pod by running

```
sum by (pod) (kube_pod_container_info)
```

However, the kube_pod_container_info doesn't tell me the node the containers are running on.

However,  I can't find a way to get the total number of containers on each node by chaining these two queries together. Is there an existing query that already does this for me?

Comment: Update, I was able to use kubelet's prometheus metrics to get this information

    kubelet_running_container_count

holds this information in case anyone's interested

Comment: it would be great if you post your answer here